# Python console exits immediately from windows command prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know this is too basic. But this has turn me around.

I had Python2.7 before I installed Python 3.

But again I had to fall back on Python2.7 for some reasons.

But this gave me a problem. The python console doesn't open anymore from my command prompt. It just prints the python version and toggles back to command prompt.

```
C:\Users\may>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

C:\Users\may>
```

I have set the environment variable to:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

But it doesn't work.
Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall?

Comment: try launching it like `python -v` and search for some relevant info in the output.

Comment: reinstalling worked.